# HTML5 canvas Image issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I making a game in HTML5 and this image wont draw. In the chrome js console it says there's nothing wrong with it.

Declaring the image:
`var wall1 = new Image();`

calling the onload:

```
function render(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    wall1.onload = drawwall(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    wall1.src = "assets/slide.jpg";
}
```

Draw wall function:

```
function drawwall(numb, dist, hm){
    ctx.drawImage(wall1,numb*4,4,4,height[hm]*3/dist,numb*4,1,4,height[hm]*3/dist);
}
```

I've tried `return ctx.drawImage(...` and `return Function(){ctx.drawImage(...` but it still wont work.

Comment: you are executing drawwall and setting its return value to onload, not setting the actual function to onload. try `onload = drawwall.bind(null,arg1, arg2, arg3);`

Comment: this did not work is it chrome or somthing

Comment: What is the size of your canvas, and what arguments do you pass into render?

Comment: my canvas is 640 x 480 and im passing 4,5,g g is = to 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
wall1.onload = drawwall(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

To this

```
wall1.onload = function() { drawwall(arg1, arg2, arg3); };
```

This is necessary because you need to assign a function to the `onload` property. In the erroneous code you were assigning the result of *invoking* a function.

Comment: OK does the canvas work at all? Is it just painting images that isn't working? If so my first port of call would be checking the location of the file is correct.

Comment: yes it is working I've got a another image thats drawing fine

Comment: Without seeing all your code this is a bit of a stab in the dark; what are the coordinates on ctx.drawImage(wall1,numb*4,4,4,height[hm]*3/dist,numb*4,1,4,height[hm]*3/dist); is height[hm] zero by any chance? Do a console.log(...) of the values and check them.

Comment: it gives me nan in the console

Comment: See a simplified working example of a drawing like yours here: http://jsfiddle.net/L36m3oLx/

Comment: If that has sorted your issue out could you accept the answer ;-)

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining why this change is necessary.